# JSON in Spring mvc - read json data, parse and render it in jsp

Tags: java, json, jsp, maven, spring-mvc

Hi I am going to retrieve JSON data from other website.

the JSON data from other web site can be like this:

```
{"message":"Message123","time":"time123","name":"name123", "value":"value123", "id":"id123"}
```

I am using Spring MVC & Maven.
I am a newbie in java world and web applications. 
Here is what I am to do for my web applications

```
i. Open URL connection to the other website - Succeed
ii. retrieve/read JSON data from the website
iii. Parse the data in Java controller
  - may need Map it ??
iv. hand over the data to Jsp file by model attribute
```

so I have succeed nr.1 (I think when I check the response status code)
but I am struggling with nr.2-4..

Here is my code, anyone can guide me what I should do or what I did wrong?

```
@Controller
public class FeedbackController {
  @RequestMapping(value = "/test")
  public String HTTPConnection(Model model) throws IOException {

  //==[i] : Open URL ========
       URL url = new URL("http://test.com:1234/test/data/");

    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) con;

    BASE64Encoder enc = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder();
    String username = "admin";
    String password = "1234";
    String userpassword = username + ":" + password;
    String encodedAuthorization = enc.encode(userpassword.getBytes());
    httpCon.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedAuthorization);

    // enable input and output modes (optional)
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setDoInput(true);

    System.out.println("test HTTPconnection");

    httpCon.setRequestMethod("GET"); 
    httpCon.setConnectTimeout(10000);// request time out
    httpCon.setReadTimeout(10000);

    int responseCode = httpCon.getResponseCode(); 

    System.out.print("HTTP status Code:");
    System.out.println(responseCode); // [A] returns 200 - so assume connection is uscceed

    //==[ii]: Retrieve/read json data ======
    //setting http request headers  - [Q1] Do I need this?
    httpCon.setRequestProperty("Context-Type", "application/json"); httpCon.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");//other any other
    httpCon.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "utf-8");

    httpCon.setUseCaches(false);   // [Q2] what is this for?

//==== [iii]: parse & map the data  ======

    JSONObject jsonObject = JSONObject.fromObject(json);
    String m = jsonObject.get("message").toString();
    String t = jsonObject.get("time").toString();
    String n = jsonObject.get("name").toString();


 //=== [iv] hand over the data to jsp =====
    model.addAttribute("xxx", xxx);
    return "test";
}
}
```

all this code in one controller/method, so extra questions

**[Q3]** Is that okay to be in one controller & method to open url & retrieve, parse JSON data

**[Q4]** specially, [2], [3] are wrong..

**[Q5]** for JSONObject type, I added dependecy like this in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
 <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
 <version>2.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

but still doesn't recongnize the type do I need

```
<classifier>jdk15</classifier>
```

if so, why?

Comment: Are you sure in your controller, you are receiving the json object?

Comment: No, I am not sure, the only thing I am (a little bit) sure is that the URL connection is succeed from [A]. The code snippet from [ii] to [iii], I have no confidence at all. therefore, I have asked to get advice about the part [ii] , [iii]